# 2 ways to Objective C custom init?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, instancetype

I am learning how to create custom INIT in Objective-C. There seems to be 2 ways to do so. Is there any difference between these two ways to create a custom init?

```
//First way of creating a custom init uses instancetype 

-(instancetype) init
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
    //initialization code here
   }
   return self:

}

//Second way of creating a custom init uses ID

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //initialization code here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is safe to use `instancetype` all the time, but keep in mind that the implementation (.m) is not (usually) visible to other classes. So in many cases declaring `instancetype` in the .h and `id` in the .m would result in the same amount of compile-time safety.